# How to create a list from lists?

Tags: python, list

```
fp.readline()
for line in fp:
    line_lst = line.strip().split(',')
```

Suppose I get a bunch of lists after running the code above:

```
['a','b','c']['1','2','3']['A','B','C']
```

How could I get another lists

```
['a','1','A']['b','2','B']['c','3','C']
```

from the lists instead of directly creating it?

Comment: Do you always want the first element in the lists?

Comment: @Arc676 Actually I was wondering how can I convert the lists into ['a','1','A']['b','2','B']['c','3','C']

Comment: You should include this kind of information in your post. You can [edit] it to do so.

Comment: @Arc676 Thank you! I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all lists have same number of elements

```
my_lists = [my_list_1, my_list2, ...]
for i in xrange(len(my_lists[0])):
    print [l[i] for l in my_lists]
```

An example...

```
>>> my_lists = [['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'],['A','B','C']]
>>> for i in xrange(len(my_lists[0])):
...     print [l[i] for l in my_lists]
... 
['a', '1', 'A']
['b', '2', 'B']
['c', '3', 'C']
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @Chrisiicandy It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved, or close to a resolution. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."

Comment: @DebosmitRay kk

Comment: Another solution for fun : `c = list(product(*my_lis))` then `[my_list[k] for k in range(0, len(my_list), 13)]` It'll give the desired output ... But what a bad solution :-p

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
all_list = [['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'],['A','B','C']]
result = [x[0] for x in all_list]
print(result)
```

This is called **list comprehension** in Python.

For your need, you should use **zip** function here, the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is give by @Arc676.

```
all_list = [['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'],['A','B','C']]
# result = list(zip(all_list[0], all_list[1], all_list[2]))
# if you have more list in all_list, you could use this
result = list(zip(*all_list))
print(result)
```

Comment: `all_list = [['a','b','c']['1','2','3']['A','B','C']]`? That is not going to compile.

Comment: @DebosmitRay Sorry, you should add comma, in my phone, I forget to add it.

Comment: @Arc676 That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below.

```
var aggregateList = line_lst.map(function (value) { return value[0]; });
```

EDIT: Oops, thought I was in the javascript section, for python:

```
aggregateList = map(lambda value: value[0], line_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it... but it's really just getting the first item from each list, so I'm not sure if it's exactly what you want

```
new_list = []
for sub_list in line_lst:
    new_list.append(sub_list[0])
```

you could also do this (which I like better)

```
new_list = [sub_list[0] for sub_list in line_lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
zip(['a','b','c'], ['1','2','3'], ['A','B','C'])
```

Which gives:

> [('a', '1', 'A'), ('b', '2', 'B'), ('c', '3', 'C')]